# How to highlight command prompt in Guake / ArchLinux?

Tags: prompt, guake

I am starting to use Arch Linux / Mate, and Guake with it (last versions). I would like Guake can highlight the command prompt, like in [this image](https://www.google.com.ec/search?q=guake&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiq8bSZsYLOAhWKVh4KHdZuA6oQ_AUICCgB&biw=1440&bih=809#tbm=isch&q=guake%20arch&imgrc=mugT7FlPs5Ri3M%3A). You can see the prompt is light green, and the other text is white.

Actually Guake is showing like [this one](https://www.google.com.ec/search?q=guake&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiq8bSZsYLOAhWKVh4KHdZuA6oQ_AUICCgB&biw=1440&bih=809#tbm=isch&q=guake%20arch%20linux&imgrc=QHsXDy8WyF-xPM%3A), with no differences between prompt and the rest of the text.

My intention is to differ from the command prompt and the other text showed in Guake.

Is there a way or a theme to make this difference?
Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried setting it the normal way? Look for "linux color prompt", or see the [Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Bash/Prompt_customization), you should get several thousand solutions. If there's something special about guake that makes them fail, please edit your question to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

That is your shell prompt and can be customised by modifying the value of the PS1 builtin variable.
See this write up from [LinuxNix.com](http://www.linuxnix.com/linuxunix-shell-ps1-prompt-explained-in-detail/).

There are [handy generators](http://ezprompt.net) on the web which can help in  creating them.

Answer (score 0):

If you type this into your terminal:

```
echo $PS1
```

then you will see what's making your prompt do what it's doing. If you want to understand that, you'll have to read the article linked by Jak Gibb above. If you want to set the prompt to green, try typing this in your terminal:

```
PS1="\e[1;33m\\w\$ \e[m \$"
```

Here's what that's doing... \e[ is an escape code... 1;33m is ansi-speak for turn green... \\w says print working directory... and \e[m means go back to normal color... finally, \$ just prints the dollar sigh.

Now in bash you can make it permanent just by putting that variable assignment in the .bashrc file but for the life of me, I can't find the equivalent profile for Guake. A good workaround would be to make a script that you could run at the beginning of each session.